# Pausing between instructions

Tags: assembly

I want to display two symbols on seven segment display one after the other. 
But with the following code, the first symbol could n't viewed as it is overwritten immediately by the second symbol.

How can I make the first symbol visible for sometime before being overwritten?

```
     array: EQU $420
     ledValues: EQU $410

       ORG $400
    varB: DC.W 2
    index: DC.B 0
    varN: DC.B 4

       ORG ledValues
    DC.B $5F, $06 , $3B, $2F, $66, $6D, $7D, $07, $7F, $6F

       ORG $1000
   DC.B 0

       ORG $4000
  Start:
  LDD #$2000
  STD $0002

  LDS #$2000
  ANDCC #$BF

   Loop:
     LDD varB
     ADDD #1
     LDX #10
     IDIV
     STD varB
     LDAA index
     LDY #array
     STAB a, y
     INCA
     STAA index
     CMPA varN
     BEQ FinishGenerating
     BRA Loop

   FinishGenerating:
     LDAA #0
     STAA index
  ShowElement:
     LDAA index
     LDY #array
     LDAB a, y
     LDY #ledValues
     LDAA b,y 
     STAA $0000

  InterruptCheck:
    LDAA $1000
    CMPB #1
  BNE InterruptCheck

    LDAB #10
    STAB $1000

 INC index

 LDAB varN
 CMPB index
 BEQ FinishGenerating
 BRA ShowElement

Finish:
 BRA Finish

  Interrupt:
   LDAB #1
   STAB $1000
   RTI

     ORG $FFF4
   DC.W Interrupt

     ORG $FFFE
   DC.W Start
```

Comment: using debugger and breakpoint?

Comment: Please add the architecture you're targeting.

Comment: generally you burn clocks with some sort of nop and/or counter that burns some time (or timer).  with a seven segment display generally though you have to blink the digits as they are often not wired so they can all be on at the same time.  initially use some nops or a loop of N nops, then later a timer if required.

Comment: Looks like 6809 assembly.